# Android layout_below way of working

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

So I have a layout that contains a ListView...and underneath the ListView I have various other elements...my problem is that if the ListView gets a lot of elements, then the elements from the bottom disapear from the screen....How can i solve this?

My layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/header"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/name_header"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:text="@string/product"
            />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/quantity_header"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="@string/quantity"
                android:gravity="center"
            />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/total_price_header"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="@string/price"
                android:gravity="center"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewOrder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        </ListView>

        <View android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listViewOrder"
        />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/total_cost"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line2"
        />

        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total_cost">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_home"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_work"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_work"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />
        </RadioGroup>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

EDIT : The problem was in my approach..what I needed was a TableLayout...and the element outside to be a ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Put a layout_above on the listView.  If you use layout_below on the lower view, it will size the listview first, then find a place ot put the thing below it, which will be off the screen.  If you do a layout_above on the listView putting it above those elements, it will layout the elements below it first, then layout the listview above those, forcing it into the remaining space.  Just remember to put the bottommost item aligned to the parent's bottom.

Comment: your approach makes my list to "forcing it into the remaining space" ...what i would like is to have it with it's normal size...and if this size is too big, to have the screen scrollable...if that is possible :)

Comment: Then you don't want a list view.  A list view is a scrollable view with infinite rows that intelligently manages those rows such that only n are viewable at a time.  Making the entire screen scrollable with the LV scrollable within it would screw things up.  What you want it to use a TableLayout and programatically add 1 row per item instead of a listView.  You use a listview so the screen doesn't have to scroll.

Comment: so basically you are saying to use ta table instead of the listView ? I will try this solution ..and come back with your reward if it works :)